# Phrases for qualitative comparison

Tags: comparisons, science, scientific-language

Suppose we have find a relation between two quantities X and Y. When we say "The more Y, the more X" is it implied that the relation between Y and X is linear?

Comment: No, merely that it's proportional. The nature of the function is unspecified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, it only describes a direct relationship. It has no  bearing on the mathematical nature of the relationship beyond that

It could be linear, non-linear, proportional.